# full width button in android layout using xml

Tags: android, xml

i want to create full width button in android using xml.
here is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/menu"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/manulogo" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
    android:text="Drawable left" 
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show us the complete layout. And specify what problem you're facing.

Comment: In your layout button already fill full screen,please clarify question.

Comment: Try to remove left and right padding from parent layout.

Comment: you can find your answer in this post[how to have image and text center within a button][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817449/how-to-have-image-and-text-center-within-a-button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get rid of 16 dp margin on left and right, you will need to remove the padding properties from main relative layout.

Also, you can't use property `orientation` with relative layout. That's for Linear layout.

And you should use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent` for better practice:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/menu"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        android:text="Drawable left" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This modified code works fine.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have do like this

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

parent layout have left and right padding so remove it and `Button` will be full screen

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/menu"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/manulogo" />
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
        android:text="Drawable left" 
      />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: First i have ANSWER this question and user has also accept my answer for what reason he has unaccepted my answer i don't know and now some buddy has down what can you explain why ??? down voted my answer ?