# Customize AppCompatButton drawableLeft?

Tags: android, button, android-appcompat, compound-drawables

How can I place `drawableLeft` and button text of `AppCompatButton` like in the image below?

[image: AppCompatButton]

I have tried to apply `paddingLeft`, but the text is moving away from the drawable to the right.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/filterBy"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_btn_filter"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/filter_by"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />
```

And so far the result is looking like

[image]

Layout

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/profileHeader"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/findFriends"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_btn_search"
                android:text="@string/find_friends"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/filterBy"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_btn_filter"
                android:text="@string/filter_by"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />
      </LinearLayout>
```

And the interpreted requirement for making things clear.

> *Using `layout_weight` property am adjusting the width of both buttons and what i have to do is, the text should be in center of the button
>   and the drawable should be aligned near left of the text.*

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 5):

use

```
 android:drawablePadding=""
```

Comment: `drawablePadding` only makes padding b/w the button text and drawable.

Comment: Completely your misunderstand my query plz see the updated one.

Answer (score 0):

probably you can't, if you want like this then you have to make it using complex layout like this [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817449/how-to-have-image-and-text-center-within-a-button)

Answer (score 0):

Add padding to the right too; that will push the text and the drawable closer together. Keep adjusting these values to get desired result.

See below:

```
android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_water_now"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="21dp"
```

Sample result:

[image: Here is the results]