# I want to add image and text in center like in button

Tags: android, android-button, material-components-android

[image]

Below is what I tried to do both icon and text in the center of a button but icon gets top of the image. I want them to be in the center.

```
 <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                   >
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/baseline_home_24"
                    />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/btnCleaner"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Cleaner"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: its good if you can share your expected output as image

Comment: i have updated picture

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817449/how-to-have-image-and-text-center-within-a-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_home_24"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnCleaner"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cleaner"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I just align the textView in the right of imageView. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Do Simply like this:-

```
 <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#fff">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/baseline_home_24"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"  />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/btnCleaner"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
/>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: this gives the same result i m having before

Comment: please add these properties in the TextView I forget to add. "android:marginLeft="10dp"

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?

```
<FrameLayout style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@null"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:text="Button Challenge" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's relevant to your requirement:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/grey_back"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Do stuff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If my answer helps you then please mark as a right my answer from tick mark otherwise i'm gonna remove this answer brother : https://www.google.com/search?q=right+mark+as+an+answer+stackoverflow&sxsrf=ACYBGNQVsfXj9VeT9WRKWerxeSRoAMe2uQ:1579936139192&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQk-DimJ7nAhWBc30KHdm9CGAQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1517&bih=730#imgrc=9_JN49MpzDykBM:

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using only Textview like below:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:gravity="center">
           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnCleaner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cleaner"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/yourDrawable" // your image 
            android:drawablePadding="3dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

if you want image at left of text then use **drawableLeft** & if at right of text then use **drawableRight**. Also you can give padding to image from text by **drawablePadding**.

Comment: drawableleft will locate the icon on starting left not in center

Comment: @HassanRana if you put set your textview layout centerInParent true then left drawable automatically comes to center with text

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the new `MaterialButton` class, found in Google's [Material Components](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/)

For example:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/material_icon_button"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/icon_button_label_enabled"
    app:icon="@drawable/icon_24px"
    app:iconPadding="8dp"/>
```

Would display a button with an icon that has padding

The source code of this button and the rest of these components can be found on the project's Github [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton.java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**`MaterialButton`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) provided by the official [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

You have to apply the `app:iconGravity="textStart"` attribute.
Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        app:icon="@drawable/..."
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        android:text="@string/..."/>
```

[image]

Also you can change the padding between the icon and the text with the attribute `app:iconPadding="xxdp"`.