# Copying android:drawableStart for RadioButtons in API 8

Tags: android, android-layout

I need a custom radio button with a custom background, centered text, an icon immediately before the text, but without the default indicator.

Currently, I have the following code:

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:button="@null"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_rbtn_custom"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
    android:text="Lorem ipsum…" />
```

The problem is the icon defined in `drawableLeft`, is pushed all the way to the left, i.e.

```
[icon]____Lorem ipsum…________
```

I need this:

```
____[icon]Lorem ipsum…________
```

The same thing happens when I use `android:button="@drawable/icon`; the icon is place at the left-most part of the `View`, and the text is then centred inside the left-over space (rather than being centred relative to the entire `View`). I am Android API 8, so I can't use `drawableStart`, so I need a way to duplicate its behaviour (at least I *assume* that's what it does). The text is dynamic, and **will** change at runtime, so I can't really hard code the padding.

My question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634191/how-to-center-icon-and-text-in-a-android-button-with-width-set-to-fill-parent), but that guy only needed a `Button`, but I need a `RadioButton` that'll work in a `RadioGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

First thoughts would be to try

```
android:paddingLeft="#db"
```

where "#db" would be the number of pixels it would take to center everything

---

After trying your code and replacing the background and icon to local resources I had, I was unable to recreate the issue you are having. Could it be possible that the icon you are using has transparent pixels on its right edge?

Comment: which issue are you talking about? the `drawableStart` not appearing, or the image not appearing right next to the text?

Comment: I used both drawableStart and drawableLeft and both resulted in the icon showing up as well as the icon was flush next to the text. I was unsuccessful in creating the gap that you are experiencing between the text and icon and had no issues with drawableStart not appearing. Because of this I suggest switching icons and seeing if its a problem with the icon itself or is code related.

Comment: the reason I suggested paddingLeft was if you could get the two together, then you could "center" them by pushing them towards center since I believe android:gravity="center" will only center the text

Comment: `drawableLeft` works for me, but the only problem is the gap. The text is dynamic, so I can't hard code the padding. As for why `drawableStart` won't work, I just figured out it's cause I am using API 8, and `drawableStart` is API 14 haha.

Comment: Good to know about drawableStart! I wouldn't have ever thought of that. I am sorry I couldn't have been more help

Comment: It's all good. Do update if you figure it out. Also, thanks very much for your time.

Comment: You can't see the problem while using layout_width="wrap_content" because the view will shrink to the size of the text plus the drawableLeft. You need to use match_parent. Then the Button will stretch to a size larger then it's text and icon. The text will be centered and the icon will stick to the left border of the view.