# Is it possible to use ImageSpan in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to tweak the ImageButtonRenderer in Xamarin.Forms.Labs to render ImageButtons with the image & text centered (as a block) on the image button, rather than having the image aligned to the left/right edge of the button, as is the default behavior of the renderer.

I came across a [StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634191) stating that this kind of layout can be achieved in Android using ImageSpan - however, when I translated the code to Xamarin.Forms C# the text is displayed, but not the image.  Can anyone see something obviously wrong with this code?...

***source** is the ImageSource value of the ImageButton control*

```
var handler = new FileImageSourceHandler();

var bitmap = await handler.LoadImageAsync(source, this.Context);

if (bitmap != null)
{
    var bitmapWidth = this.ImageButton.ImageWidthRequest.Equals(0) ? bitmap.Width : (int)(this.ImageButton.ImageWidthRequest);
    var bitmapHeight = this.ImageButton.ImageHeightRequest.Equals(0) ? bitmap.Height : (int)(this.ImageButton.ImageHeightRequest);

    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(Resources, bitmap);
    var scaledDrawable = new ScaleDrawable(drawable, 0, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight).Drawable;
    scaledDrawable.SetBounds(0, 0, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight);

    var scaledBitmap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, true);

    var leftPadding = (int)this.ImageButton.ButtonPadding.Left;
    var rightPadding = (int)this.ImageButton.ButtonPadding.Right;
    var topPadding = (int)this.ImageButton.ButtonPadding.Top;
    var bottomPadding = (int)this.ImageButton.ButtonPadding.Bottom;

    Control.SetPadding(leftPadding, topPadding, rightPadding, bottomPadding);
    Control.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal | GravityFlags.CenterVertical;

    switch (this.ImageButton.Orientation)
    {
        case ImageOrientation.ImageToRight:
            var rightButtonLabel = new SpannableString(string.Format("{0} ", this.Control.Text));
            //rightButtonLabel.SetSpan(new ImageSpan(scaledBitmap), rightButtonLabel.Length() - 1, rightButtonLabel.Length(), SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);
            //rightButtonLabel.SetSpan(new ImageSpan(scaledDrawable, SpanAlign.Bottom), rightButtonLabel.Length() - 1, rightButtonLabel.Length(), SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);
            //rightButtonLabel.SetSpan(new ImageSpan(scaledDrawable), rightButtonLabel.Length() - 1, rightButtonLabel.Length(), SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);
            rightButtonLabel.SetSpan(new ImageSpan(Forms.Context, scaledBitmap, SpanAlign.Bottom), rightButtonLabel.Length() - 1, rightButtonLabel.Length(), SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);
            Control.SetText(rightButtonLabel, Android.Widget.TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
            break;

        case ImageOrientation.ImageToLeft:
        default:
            var leftButtonLabel = new SpannableString(string.Format(" {0}", this.Control.Text));
            //leftButtonLabel.SetSpan(new ImageSpan(scaledBitmap), 0, 1, SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);
            //leftButtonLabel.SetSpan(new ImageSpan(scaledDrawable, SpanAlign.Bottom), 0, 1, SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);
            //leftButtonLabel.SetSpan(new ImageSpan(scaledDrawable), 0, 1, SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
            leftButtonLabel.SetSpan(new ImageSpan(Forms.Context, scaledBitmap, SpanAlign.Bottom), 0, 1, SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);
            Control.SetText(leftButtonLabel, Android.Widget.TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
            break;
    }
}
```

The text centers just fine, but there's no image.  I've tried a few different ImageSpan overloads with Drawable, Bitmaps, using the Forms.Context, and none of them work.

**Is there some limitation with using ImageSpan in Xamarin.Forms?**

Comment: No there is no limitation to using anything from Android in Xamarin.Forms, some stuff might be a bit more quirky to set up and get working, because you are brawling with the Framework, but you shouldn't be limited to what you can do in custom Views.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is year old question. Whatever, I guess [this](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/140341/#Comment_140341) post can help with that problem.

Just need to load images to some (invisible) view, then your `ImageSpan` images would display.