# Set drawable position inside button

Tags: android, android-button, android-drawable

I've got a button and a drawable on the left of the text, but I want the drawable to be closer to the text. So I need to move the drawable.

I've defined android:drawableLeft but the content of the button is not centered.

Here is my code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/addsubject"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/addsubject"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/custombutton1" />
```

Here is how it looks now:

[image]

And here is how I'd like it to be:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: try adding `android:gravity="center"` to your xml?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634191/how-to-center-icon-and-text-in-a-android-button-with-width-set-to-fill-parent/.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/addsubject"
    android:layout_width="160dip"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    android:drawablePadding="2dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="30dip"
    android:paddingRight="26dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/addsubject"
    android:textSize="13dip" />
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! The trick was to use drawableLeft and drawableRight and adjust them to fit. Thank you!

Comment: it is working but it is not a flexible according to device size.

Answer (score 20):

Use the **`app:iconGravity="textStart"`** attribute in the `MaterialButton`

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        ../>
```

[image]

If you want to reduce the padding between the icon and the text just use the **`app:iconPadding`** attribute:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"/>
```

[image]

Comment: your answer will never work until you apply Material component theme to the button like this android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"

Answer (score 6):

I got this result by simply putting these properties to the button specifically

```
<Button
    ...
    android:paddingLeft="60dp"
    android:drawablePadding="-50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_button_icon"
    />
```

You can tune in with your own values for your desired results.

*Cheers* :-)

Comment: Thanks, it works. But delete `android:padding` if you have it. In other case an icon will stand left and a text will be centered. Also result depends on a width of a button.

Comment: The solution is bad as this way the button will look differently on different screen sizes.

Comment: @definera can you please propose a better solution for this view(button) which can adapt different screen sizes?

Comment: @ImtiazAbir Perhaps using SpannableString with ImageSpan is an option. Haven't tried it yet personally, so I can't give a specific example.

Answer (score 3):

I done this simply using paddingLeft and paddingRight. Its works!
`...
 android:paddingLeft="25dp" 
 android:paddingRight="25dp"`/>

Answer (score 1):

The padding between the left border of button and right border of the icon is controlled by `android:paddingLeft` property. The padding between the icon and the text is defined by `android:drawablePadding` property.

Add these two properties to you button and set the values you are happy with.

```
<Button
    ...
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LinearLayout as your button by adding OnClickListener and customize however you want.

```
<LinearLayout          
    android:layout_width="160dip"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@drawable/custombutton1">

    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:scaleType="center">

    </ImageView>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/addsubject"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also other possibilities that you want to inflate the drawable/icon programatically, after reading a while and using a lot of combination using XMLs, but still doesn't works,

You might want to fork below library instead, to suits your use-cases, such as, customizing the view, position, etc programatically, see below reference:

1. [Drawable/icon aligned with text](https://github.com/pnc/IconButton), see [sample here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pnc/IconButton/master/images/demo.png)
2. [Button like facebook sign-in](https://github.com/medyo/Fancybuttons), see [sample here](https://github.com/medyo/Fancybuttons)
3. For RadioButton, see [full gist code here](https://gist.github.com/siyamed/7278413851d3a1d02ffc)

P.S: Copyrighted and regards to the author

Answer (score 0):

for Materialbutton, you have to use the **icon** attribute and you can also change its tint with **iconTint** like this example:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_cancel"
    app:iconTint="@color/black"
    android:text="text" />
```