# Image left of the text when button is bigger then the text

Tags: android

I would like to create a button where an image is just left of the text even if the button is bigger then the text as shown below:

[image]

Sure, I can use

```
android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/image"
```

but then the image is aligned to the left side of the button not to the left side of the text.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8386510/833647

Comment: what if You set gravity="left" ? Does this overlap with the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

You can also have

```
android:weightSum="2"
```

or adjust layout_weight

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/image"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do that realy answer the question? There was a button we talking about. The problem is not having the image on the left side of the text. The problem is to have it AND in a button context. That is because we want to keep the click-animation.

Comment: You can also use a textview as a button. Not necessary always use a BUTTON as a button. Just add onClicklistener to a textview. And it acts as a button.

Comment: The answer to your question is: you cannot do anything with a Button. Use other layouts, and make it animate on click.

Comment: Nooooo dear !!! You can. I was just suggesting to use a TextView which can also act like a button.

Answer (score 0):

Try these in yours **XML** layout:-

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/black"//PUT HERE BUTTON BACKGROUND RESOURCE
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/age_icon"//PUT HERE YOURS IMAGE
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text is here"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
```