# left drawable alignment with text in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-canvas, android-view, textview

I am new to custom view and didn't know much about canvas in android, 
I wanted to align a left drawable to right side of layout along with the text(whether multiline or not) of same textview as in this image [image]

In the above image, i wanted to align $ image along with text($20.0 -$90.0 /hour) and must be in center if text is multiline and i don't want to use any extra layouts. Thanks in advance

This is my basic xml,

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ad_post_tv_noDays"
            style="@style/textView"
            android:text="20 days"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/color60"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_calender"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />

        <TextView
            style="@style/textView"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/ad_post_tv_wage"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="$8 - $12/hour"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ad_post_tv_noDays"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
            android:gravity="right|center"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_dollar"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I had tried to implement it with custom views, it works for small text but when the text got bigger,it gets weird, my code image is as follows,[image]

Comment: @inkedTechie, i had just created the simple layout don't custom because i don't know where to start. Check my edited question

Comment: @VikramSingh I dont understand why are you using `leftdrawable` property for textviews instead of independent `imageview`.

Comment: @misho, if i have the property available, then why should i go for adding another view.

Comment: @VikramSingh because it is much much easier and there are absolutely no reasons why you should not

Comment: @misho, dear mate i wanted to work with custom views, and i had achieved it for small text but gets weired for large text...anyway thanks mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
package views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.upsilon.docta.R;


public class MyTempView extends TextView {
    public MyTempView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
public MyTempView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.back_text_color)
    Paint textPaint = getPaint();
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    textPaint.getTextBounds(getText().toString(), 0, getText().length(), bounds);
    int textWidth = bounds.width();
    Resources res = getResources();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_close);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, getHeight() / 2 - bitmap.getHeight() / 2, textPaint);
    canvas.translate(bitmap.getWidth(), 0);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
}
```

Comment: Please add right padding after canvas.translate equal to translation distance

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ad_post_tv_noDays"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_cart_final"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="20 days"
    android:textColor="@color/blue_btn_bg_color" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ad_post_tv_wage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_cart_final"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:text="$8 - $12/hour"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" /></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is that style u have added?

Comment: <style name="textView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/color97</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">7dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>

Comment: i want the second textview to be right aligned along with left drawable not this one ....and thanks

Comment: still not working as left drawable is in left and text is in right and too distance between these two

Comment: are you sure?check again