# x coordinate with canvas.draw with custom textview not working

Tags: android, android-canvas, textview, android-custom-view, android-custom-attributes

I had successfully created an answer of my [This question(left drawable alignment with text in andorid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912539/left-drawable-alignment-with-text-in-andorid)
but the problem is that the canvas.drawText x co-ordinate is not working properly as the x co-ordinate is not affecting the position of text.

Here is the result with overlapped text on drawable,
[image]

I just wanted to remove the overlap and give the distance between the drawable and text on canvas.

Here is my code as follows,

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
android.widget.TextView;
import cl.tt.R;

public class CenterDrawableButton extends TextView{
private Drawable mDrawableCenter;

public CenterDrawableButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null);
}

public CenterDrawableButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public CenterDrawableButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public CenterDrawableButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    if(attrs!=null){
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CenterDrawableButton, 0, 0);
        try {
         setCenterDrawable(a.getDrawable(R.styleable.CenterDrawableButton_drawableCenter));
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }
}

public void setCenterDrawable(@Nullable Drawable center) {
    int[] state;
    state = getDrawableState();
    if (center != null) {
        center.setState(state);
        center.setBounds(0, 0, center.getIntrinsicWidth(), center.getIntrinsicHeight());
        center.setCallback(this);
    }
    mDrawableCenter = center;
    invalidate();
    requestLayout();
}
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (mDrawableCenter != null) {
        setMeasuredDimension(Math.max(getMeasuredWidth(), mDrawableCenter.getIntrinsicWidth()),
                Math.max(getMeasuredHeight(), mDrawableCenter.getIntrinsicHeight()));
    }
}

@Override
protected void drawableStateChanged() {
    super.drawableStateChanged();
    if (mDrawableCenter != null) {
        int[] state = getDrawableState();
        mDrawableCenter.setState(state);
        mDrawableCenter.setBounds(0, 0, mDrawableCenter.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                mDrawableCenter.getIntrinsicHeight());
    }
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (mDrawableCenter != null) {
        float textWidth = getPaint().measureText((String)getText());
        int newPosition=getWidth()-((int)textWidth+getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight()+mDrawableCenter.getIntrinsicWidth()+ (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._5sdp));
        if(newPosition>0) {
            canvas.translate(newPosition, (getHeight() - mDrawableCenter.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2);
            mDrawableCenter.draw(canvas);
            canvas.save();
            Paint textPaint = new Paint();
            int yPos = (int) ((getHeight() - ((textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent())) / 2));
            canvas.drawText(getText().toString(), newPosition, yPos, textPaint);
            canvas.restore();
        }else
        {
            int gnewPosition=getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight()+(int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._5sdp);
            canvas.translate(gnewPosition, (getHeight() - mDrawableCenter.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2);
            mDrawableCenter.draw(canvas);
            canvas.save();
            int nggewPosition=getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight()+mDrawableCenter.getIntrinsicWidth()+ (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._5sdp);
            Paint textPaint = new Paint();
            int yPos = (int) (getHeight() - ((textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent())) / 2);
            canvas.translate(nggewPosition, yPos);
            canvas.drawText(getText().toString(), nggewPosition, yPos, textPaint);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }
}
```

}

here is the attr,

```
 <attr name="drawableCenter" format="reference"/>
<declare-styleable name="CenterDrawableButton">
    <attr name="drawableCenter"/>
</declare-styleable>
```